# Modify vim (neovim) quote pairing to pair back tick with single quote in files with certain extensions

Tags: vim, neovim

### Context:

Vim and Neovim pair single quotes (`'`) in several useful ways. In particular:

1. When you enter `'` vim generates another `'` and places your cursor between the pair.
2. The text between the `'`s is treated as a text object that vim can operate on.

The same behavior holds for back ticks (`) which vim pairs with a second back tick.

### Question:

This is great; however, in some contexts a back tick should pair with a single quote rather than with a second back tick. My questions are:

- Where is this behavior controlled?
- And is this different in vim and neovim?
- What are the my options for modifying this behavior so that a backtick pairs with a single quote only in certain contexts (i.e. files with certain extensions), while maintaining the default behavior elsewhere?

### Examples:

#### Latex

In Latex opening double quotes are written using two backticks (``) rather than a double quote (") and are closed with two single quotes (''). In this case here the desired pairing would be two backticks and two single quotes with the cursor in the middle. Additionally, the text object should be the text *between* the set of backticks and the set of single quotes.

The [csquotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes?lang=en) package helpfully suggested below by [Friedrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796259/friedrich) helps with the Latex case, but I'm interested in something that would address this more generally.

#### Stata

In Stata local macros and strings that include double quotes both use this pattern. A simple example:

```
local foo bar 
di "`foo'"
generate one_dbl_quote = `"""'
```

This puts the string `bar` into a local macro named `foo` then prints the contents of `foo` to the console, then creates a string variable holding a single double quote.

Comment: I guess you're talking about LaTeX files? Being more concrete will improve your chances of getting better answers. For LaTeX specifically, a possible workaround may be to use the [csquotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes?lang=en) package.

Comment: Interesting package, and good suggestion. Added examples.

Comment: You may find [How can I treat LaTeX quotes as a text object? on Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-can-i-treat-latex-quotes-as-a-text-object) useful - some of the answers will also work for Stata.

Comment: Yes! This is great, thanks for hunting this down. I was looking for an answer to implement in the editor so I was trying to avoid saying Stata specific language. Never would have thought to look for 'Latex quotes'. Once I get something working I'll post an answer (unless someone beats me to it. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: And I don't have the faintest idea of Stata :-) Anyhow, I tried to answer as well as I could. Feel free to point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, several answers of [How can I treat LaTeX quotes as a text
object? on Vi and Vim
SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-can-i-treat-latex-quotes-as-a-text-object)
apply to this question as well.

I'll not try to replicate all of the answers here but the [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/750/4866) by user
[superjer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/195/superjer) defines new mappings
for `aq` and `iq` text-objects (see [`:help text-objects`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#text-objects) for more information). The answer is lightweight and
can easily be adapted to this question. It does have the caveat that it only works for single quotes and
only if the string is in one line which seems acceptable for Stata macros (not for LaTeX though).

To enable the mappings only for the `stata` filetype (if the filetype is not
known, consider adding it using the instructions from [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype)), and create a `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/stata.vim` file like this:

```
vnoremap <buffer><silent> iq t'oT`
onoremap <buffer> iq <Cmd>normal viq<CR>
vnoremap <buffer><silent> aq f'oF`
onoremap <buffer> aq <Cmd>normal vaq<CR>
```

Or - a little bit less tidy - you could take a shortcut and just enable them via `autocmd`
based on file extension in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup quotes-text-objects
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNew,BufEnter *.dta vnoremap <buffer><silent> iq t'oT`
    autocmd BufNew,BufEnter *.dta onoremap <buffer> iq <Cmd>normal viq<CR>
    autocmd BufNew,BufEnter *.dta vnoremap <buffer><silent> aq f'oF`
    autocmd BufNew,BufEnter *.dta onoremap <buffer> aq <Cmd>normal vaq<CR>
augroup END
```

Note that this uses `<buffer>` mappings so they don't leak out to non-Stata
files.
Instead of using `iq` and `aq`, you might even decide to go crazy and overwrite the default operators `` i` `` and `` a` ``.

For strings spanning multiple lines, things get tricky fast. In that case, I'd suggest using a plugin such as the two mentioned in the linked question's answers:
[vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich/) or - for LaTeX
specifically - [textobj-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex).

If you like any of these suggestions, visit [Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com) and give the respective authors your upvote!

Comment: This is great! The only minor note is that for the case of the Stata it seems like i` operator is the only one that would need to be overwritten for Stata since single quotes are never used in pairs and double quotes function normally.

Comment: Also, thanks for letting me know about [Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) sort of amazed at myself for not checking to see if there was a separate site. I followed the links and upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

Friedrich's answer does a great job addressing the second part of my question: getting n/vim to treat the text inside the `' as a text object. I'm also interested in getting vim to generate the correct closing punctuation. Currently, when I type a backtick vim generates a second one, this is great in markdown and other places, but not what I want in LaTeX and Stata. I wrote a simple snippet (a vscode snippet that I load via luasnip).

In my `.config/nvim/vscodesnips/stata.json` file I have:

```json
{
    "call local macro": {
        "prefix":   "`",
        "body":     "`${1:local_name}'$0",
        "description":  "when calling local macros pair backtick correctly"
    },

    "manky double quoted list stata string": {
        "prefix":   "`\"",
        "body":     "`\" \"${1:item1}\" \"${2:item2}\" \"'",
        "description":  "this really is how you put a quoted list into a stata local and how you put double quotes into a string"
    }
}
```

Together with Friedrich's answer this gets me the behavior I'm looking for, though I'm not entirely satisfied with using a snippet to solve this.